# Scalatra, Handling POST request with Gzip encoding

Tags: scala, http-post, gzip, scalatra, content-encoding

I have a Scalatra API with a POST method, which is invoked by an external API that sends gzip encoded messages. But I am unable to read the body of the post request, and when I try to read the body of POST or try to decompress it, I get the exception:

```
MalformedInputException: Input length = 1.
```

If I route the incoming POST request to fiddler, the fiddler handles the message correctly and states that the message is encoded, and after decoding, I can see the correct message in the body of the request

here are the things I have tried:

```
val body = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(request.body.getBytes))
```

Same exception is thrown by:

```
logger.info(s"Response body..." + request.body )
```

I also tried reading the body as json, but it returns JNothing:

```
logger.info(s"Response body...\n${parsedBody}" )
```

here are the POST headers:

```
(Expect,100-continue)
(Connection,keep-alive)
(Content-Encoding,gzip)
(Content-Type,application/json)
(Content-Length,3500)
```

here is part of the stack tract:

```
    Parsing the request body failed, because:
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at scala.io.BufferedSource.mkString(BufferedSource.scala:96) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at org.scalatra.servlet.RichRequest$$anonfun$body$1.apply(RichRequest.scala:181) ~[scalatra_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
        at org.scalatra.servlet.RichRequest$$anonfun$body$1.apply(RichRequest.scala:176) ~[scalatra_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at org.scalatra.servlet.RichRequest.body(RichRequest.scala:176) ~[scalatra_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
        at org.scalatra.json.JsonSupport$class.parseRequestBody(JsonSupport.scala:29) [scalatra-json_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
        at impala.api.GreetingController.parseRequestBody(GreetingController.scala:13) [classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution can be found here on the scalatra user group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatra-user/2vBBA2-CzDM